# How do I connect mic input to an effect unit and then to a mixer (using AudioCore)?

Tags: ios, core-audio

I've been able to get microphone input, connect it to a mixer, connect the mixer to a reverb2 effect, and then output all that to the speaker with CoreAudio. It looks like this:

Mic -> Mixer -> Reverb -> Speaker

This works just fine.

However, what I really want to do is this:

Mic -> Reverb -> Mixer -> Speaker

THE PROBLEM IS: I can't seem to grasp how to tell the reverb unit where/how to get its input from the mic.

If I do this, there is an error (-10865) later when the graph is initialized:

AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph, ioNode, 0, reverbNode, 0);

I've been struggling with this for days. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first set the output scope format of the mic (RemoteIO Bus 1) to the input format of the reverb audio unit.  On iOS, these 2 units have different and incompatible default or canonical data type formats, but the output format of the mic can be reconfigured.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work by adding a converter unit between the mic and the effect unit.